# SQL ORACLE, How to subtract sysdate?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime

How can I subtract the system date from the created task date in SQL ORACLE to get the difference in days, hours, minutes?

I tried this code but i get wrong values:
`TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1970-01-01 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') + (sysdate - a.CREATE_DATE_PL ), 'dd:hh24:mi:ss')  AS TT_LIFETIME`

My results is below (the report has been generated 02.06  14:05

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzPVB.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference of two `DATE` datatype values is number of *days* between them, so you have to do some arithmetic to extract days/hours/minutes, or - another option - to try `extract` with `numtodsinterval`.

For example:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (create_date_pl)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT TO_DATE ('01.06.2023 08:10', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') FROM DUAL)
  5  SELECT SYSDATE,
  6         create_date_pl,
  7         --
  8         SYSDATE - create_date_pl diff,
  9         NUMTODSINTERVAL (SYSDATE - create_date_pl, 'day') c1,
 10         EXTRACT (DAY FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL (SYSDATE - create_date_pl, 'day')) cd,
 11         EXTRACT (HOUR FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL (SYSDATE - create_date_pl, 'day')) ch,
 12         EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL (SYSDATE - create_date_pl, 'day')) cm
 13    FROM test;

SYSDATE          CREATE_DATE_PL         DIFF C1                                               CD         CH         CM
---------------- ---------------- ---------- ---------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
02.06.2023 14:29 01.06.2023 08:10 1,26333333 +000000001 06:19:12.000000000                     1          6         19

SQL>
```

When I ran that code, it was 2th of June 2023 at 14:29. Date to be subtracted was 1st of June 2023 (yesterday) at 08:10.

- `diff` represents number of days between those two values
- `c1` is what `numtodsinterval` returns
- `cd`, `ch` and `cm` contain extracted number of days/hours/minutes, i.e. difference is 1 day, 6 hours and 19 minutes

Answer (score 1):

The difference between a date and a date is a (fractional) number representing the number of days between them. You can then multiply this by 24 to get hours, or 1440 to get minutes, or 86400 to get seconds.  Don't convert anything with TO_CHAR in this process:

```
(SYSDATE - a.create_date_pl) days,
(SYSDATE - a.create_date_pl)*24 hours,
(SYSDATE - a.create_date_pl)*1440 minutes,
(SYSDATE - a.create_date_pl)*86400 seconds
```

You may then add a (fractional) number to a date, the result is another date, the original date offset by the number of days you've added to it.

```
SYSDATE + (a.expiration_date - a.create_date_pl) -- = another date
```

You may also cast `DATE`s to `TIMESTAMP`s, and then the difference would be the `INTERVAL` datatype:

```
SYSTIMESTAMP - CAST(TO_DATE('01/01/2023','MM/DD/YYYY') AS timestamp)
```

Result:

```
+000000152 07:21:21.785258
```

There are a number of functions available to extract the pieces of an interval. I however find that in most cases working with dates is the simplest, because it's not as trivial as it should be to convert an `INTERVAL` into a single number (total number of seconds, for example), whereas that's very simple with `DATE` arithmetic. `DATE`s are also simpler in that they don't include timezones, which can get quite confusing for programmers with `TIMESTAMP` logic.